# Hive QL Except clause

Tags: hive

How do I do an `EXCEPT` clause (like SQL) in Hive QL

I have 2 tables, and each table is a column of unique ids.

I want to find the list of ids that are only in table 1 but not in table 2

**Table 1**

```
apple
orange
pear
```

**Table 2**

```
apple
orange
```

In SQL you can do an EXCEPT clause (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29) but you can't do that in Hive QL

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't think there's any built-in way to do this but a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` should do the trick.

This selects all Ids from `table1` that do *not* exist in `table2`:

```
SELECT t1.id FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id=t2.id) WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use **NOT EXISTS** clause in Hive as **MINUS** equivalent.

```
SELECT t1.id FROM t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

1:

```
select distinct id from table1 where id not in (select distinct id from table2)
```

2:

```
select t1.id
from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.id is null
```